# Can I use a JavaScript inline edit library in my Angular 2 project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is the library:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Based-Content-editable-Widget-contenteditable-js/

This is used for inline editing on html pages. My code on HTML page is shown below -

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://sco7.com/del/jquery-contenteditable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#basic").editable();
        $("#paragraph").editable({
            multiline: true,
            autoselect: true
        });
        $("#alert").editable({
            multiline: true,
            saveDelay: 800,
            save: function(e, ui) {
                alert("Saving actual content: " + ui.content);
            }
        });
        $("#scalable").editable({
            multiline: true
        });
        $("#nonempty").editable({
            multiline: true,
            saveDelay: 600,
            autoselect: true,
            save: function(e, ui) {
                alert("Saving actual content: " + ui.content);
            },
            validate: function(e, ui) {
                return ui.content !== "";
            }
        });
        $("#complex").editable({
            content: "a", //only link <a> is editable
            autoselect: true,
            save: function(e, ui) {
                alert("New link: " + ui.content);
            },
            validate: function(e, ui) {
                return ui.content !== ""
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<p id="alert">
        This sample fires alert each time changed content is supposed to be saved (e.g. sent to server).
        It is currently set up to fire after 800ms delay of not typing anything.
    </p>
```

I want to use this in my Angular project. Can I use this as it is? Like the `<p id="alert">`, do I need to do this in a similar way?

Comment: why are you using library for inline editing. Why dont you use default browser feature?

Comment: I am creating an html editor, what is the other way around instead of inline editing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contenteditable` attribute or set `designmode` on html elements to make it editable. For more information you can refer [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#alert").keyup(function(){
    console.info($(this).html()); // prints edited text
    console.info("Inner Html---->"+$("#container").html()); // prints html of edited text
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id="container">
<p id="alert" contenteditable="true">
 EDIT ME
</p>
</div>
```

**Example Code**

```
<div #container>
 <p #alert contenteditable="true">EDIT ME</p>
</div>
```

**Script File**

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('container') el:ElementRef;

constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.el.nativeElement.innerHtml;      
}
```

Comment: in  edit.component.ts i can edit EDIT ME, but in angular2, how can i fetch the html content inside `<div id="container">`

Comment: a sample code is added.if this is not solving your problem share your working code using `Plunker` or `JSFiddle` @user2828442

Comment: `@ViewChild('container') el:ElementRef;` it says [ts] unused label

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Add scripts directly**

> You can add that scrips directly in your page using `$("selector")`

**index.html**

```
<h2 id="basic">
    Basic examples. Click on me to edit. Press 'ESC' or 'Tab' or click anywhere else to finish editing.
</h2>

<!--do not forget add scripts-->

<!--basic scripts-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Based-Content-editable-Widget-contenteditable-js/src/jquery-contenteditable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>

<!--your scripts-->
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="your-editable.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

**your-editable.js**

```
$("#basic").editable();
```

**Options 2: convert to directive**

> There you can convert the editable to directive to have more access on elements

**index.html**

```
 <!--options: basic, paragraph, alert, scalable, nonempty, complex-->
<h2 content="basic">
    Basic examples. Click on me to edit. Press 'ESC' or 'Tab' or click anywhere else to finish editing.
</h2>

<!--do not forget add scripts-->

<!--basic scripts-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Based-Content-editable-Widget-contenteditable-js/src/jquery-contenteditable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>

<!--your scripts-->
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="directive.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

**directive.js**

> Also you can improve this directive to get more options from developers

```
app.directive("content", function () {
  return {
     restrict: "A",
     scope: {
        content: "@"
     },
     link: function ($scope, $element) {
       switch ($scope.content) {
         case "basic":
           $element.editable();
         break;
         case "paragraph":
           $element.editable({
             multiline: true,
             autoselect: true
            });
         break;
         case "alert":
            $element.editable({
              multiline: true,
              saveDelay: 800,
              save: function (content) {
                alert("Saving actual content: " + content);
              }
         });
         break;
         case "scalable":
           $element.editable({
             multiline: true
           });
         break;
         case "nonempty":
           $element.editable({
              multiline: true,
              saveDelay: 600,
              autoselect: true,
              save: function (content) {
                 alert("Saving actual content: " + content);
              },
              validate: function (content) {
                 return content !== "";
              }});
          break;
          case "complex":
            $element.editable({
               content: "a",
               autoselect: true,
               save: function (content) {
                  alert("New link: " + content);
               },
               validate: function (content) {
                  return content !== "";
               }});
         break;
         default:
              $element.editable();
         }}}});
```

Comment: The above solution is for anguar2 ? as i am new in angular i am finding that if i create 1 component then its respective .ts file is also make along, this app.js fundamental is not clear to me, for example i created a component using cli `ng g c exportexample` , it created `export-example.component.html` and `export-example.component.ts`  .  I am also not clear about `angular.module("app", []);` , please guide me the right path to study about these basics

Comment: And where you said question related to angular 2 ? which version you use !

Comment: i am so sorry i did not mention, i am on angular2

Comment: when you create a new component angular-cli it  will create `(.html),(.ts),(.spec.ts)` and your new component get included in `app.module.ts` file as an `import` statement. `.spec.ts` can be avoided if you are not planning to write test.